# Tkinter button issue

Tags: python, tkinter, button

```py
import tkinter

win=tkinter.Tk()
win.configure(background='grey')

k=False

def g():
    k=True

v=tkinter.Button(win, text='click',  command=g)
v.pack()

while k==True:
    win.configure(background='black')

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why would you think that `while` loop would run at all?

Comment: Which, of the many issues, are you having with this code?

Comment: while loop not working

Comment: Yes – why would it work? Why do you think it would rerun after `k` has been set to True?

Comment: Well, the `while` loop *is* working. That is, it checks the value of `k`, finds it to be `False` and continues without executing anything inside the loop.

Comment: so what should I use instead of while to make it work

Comment: But what is `it work`? There are so many issues here its difficult to know what you want. Perhaps you should update your question with a description of what you want.

Comment: `Button` doesn't work as `input()` - it doesn't wait for your click. It only inform `mainloop` what it has to display in window. And `mainloop` displays window after running your `while` loop. So you see button and you click button after running `while`-loop. If you want to do something when you click button then you have to do it all inside function `g()`. And the same is with other widgets in Thinter, and whith widgets in other GUI frameworks (in other languages too).

Comment: Can you explain more with example please

Comment: you have example in answer below - it runs `win.configure(background='black')` directly in `change_color()`

Comment: What should I use to make program wait until I click button

Comment: That's precisely what the answer below does. The line: `win.mainloop()` does the waiting and detecting the button click. Then it passes control to the `change_color()` function which calls the `win.configure(...)` method and returns back to the mainloop.

Comment: you have to run code inside function assigned to button - `g()` or `change_color()` - this is how all GUIs work and you can't change it. You have `command=` to run code when button will be clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason why that `while` loop would run after the button is clicked, since (as you know) your program is run "from top to bottom", and control remains in `win.mainloop()` until the window is closed. (You can find that out by adding `print("bye!")` after that call.)

You might want to just directly call `.configure()`. (I gave the button some padding here so you can see the background change; otherwise the button may take up the entirety of the window and you won't see a change.)

```
import tkinter

win = tkinter.Tk()


def change_color():
    win.configure(background='black')


button = tkinter.Button(win, text='click', command=change_color)
button.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: i want when i click button then k become true and something happen next, so i use While but it not working so is there any way to make my idea work?

Comment: Why would you need a while loop to make "something happen"?

Comment: Cus Iam beginner my knowledge are little

Comment: Well, see the above example; clicking the button turns the background of the window black.

Comment: Your idea of a while loop is invalid in `tkinter`. Everything should be `RTC`, ie Run To Completion. You should arrange your code to be triggered by `tkinter` and run quickly and return control back.